# Logs to Elasticsearch to Apache NIFI (QueryElasticsearchHttp)

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana, apache-nifi

I'm trying to send get data from my elastic search cluster to Apache NIFI using QueryElasticsearchHttp. Using latest elastic version elasticsearch-8.6.1 and apache nifi 1.19.1.

[image: NIFI configuration]

Getting the below error.

```
2023-02-02 03:23:55,110 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] o.a.n.p.e.QueryElasticsearchHttp [QueryElasticsearchHttp[id=1024bc75-0186-1000-ddf8-9843acd89d89], null, null] Failed to read {} from Elasticsearch due to {}
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.elasticsearch.QueryElasticsearchHttp.getPage(QueryElasticsearchHttp.java:418)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.elasticsearch.QueryElasticsearchHttp.onTrigger(QueryElasticsearchHttp.java:354)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1356)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:246)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:102)
        at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

So I went through source code. it says in Apache Nifi (QueryElasticsearchHttp) Type attribute should be added. The problem is I don't have type in Elasticsearch is the any workaround or how can I set empty type to queried from Elasticsearch using lucene.

Once I set arbitrary type  in QueryElasticsearchHttp below error occurs. Because in my Elasticsearch logs no type defined.

```
2023-02-02 03:24:17,268 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] o.a.n.p.e.QueryElasticsearchHttp QueryElasticsearchHttp[id=1024bc75-0186-1000-ddf8-9843acd89d89] Elasticsearch returned code 400 with message Bad Request.
```

Comment: Does the desired index exist in Elasticsearch? Is ES reachable from NIFI?

Comment: Yes it does exists. As per my finding document_type is depreciated from the elasticsearch 8.x. Yet in the Apache NiFi 1.19.1 yet type (document_type) is mandatory. Therefore QueryElasticsearchHttp in Apache NiFi 1.19.1 is not compatible with elasticsearch 8.x.

Comment: This might require a ticket in the NIFI JIRA to fix the issue